# Requirements to run Expressjs on Server

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I created "Web Services/API" in Nodejs(Expressjs framework) on localhost and now i want to put this code into server so i want to know that What type of server supports Node.JS applications?

Does it need to be a dedicated server or something else ?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Server that has NodeJS installed :)

Comment: Pretty much any server will run node, even single board computers.  There maybe are odd CPU architectures that might not be compatible.  The main problem is binary packages, there are a lot of architecture specific ones, but express is fine.

Answer (score 0):

Usually when we want to deploy a web app, we use a hosting service. As @Gunvant Qodic mentioned you have options like AWS, Google Cloud, Microsoft Azure, Heroku, etc. If you are looking for free hosting services (that support Node.js/Express.js) that don't require credit card info then you have the following options.

- [Railway](https://railway.app/)
- [Cyclic](https://cyclic.sh/)
- [Render](https://render.com/)
- [Glitch](https://glitch.com/)